# Error when creating Excel file on server

Tags: c#, .net, ms-office

I have created an application in .Net which will create an excel file on server and will send it as attachment through email.
I am receiving following error, when the application tries to create excel file on server :

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154

Through the similar posts for this question and after some searching on internet, I found that I need to install MS office on server.

Still I would like to know, if there is any other way(i.e. without installing MS Office) through which I can achieve my requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally installed MS Office & it started working. Thank you all for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a 3rd party excel tool. Should get ClosedXML from NuGet. It has single dependency to DocumentFormat.OpenXml and it is very effective tool.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but for using this third party tool, I will have to make changes in my code. I want to know if there any simpler method for doing this, like simply adding DLLs or changes in settings.

Comment: Usage is very close to classic excel interop. You can change easy. Whatsoever, find correct dll (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel vs) versions in your solution. Use solution explorer, find interop references. And use properties to determine their versions. So download the interop library setups from Microsoft site and install to production machine.

Answer (score 0):

really depends on your needs.

if you want to create csv file, then it would be fairly simple - just dump a text file with delimiters.

if you want to create complicated excel file (xml based excel file, .xlsx and etc.), you may consider openXML, and there are also plenty of other thirdparty tools wrapping it too.

ref: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124